# How to call directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have directive that i want to call.Its spinner that works on promise...so when promise is pending to call spinner but problem is that my directive is never called.Any suggestion why this is happening?

```
'use strict';
angular.module("mainModule").directive('modulSpinner', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', '$compile', function ($timeout, $rootScope, $compile) {

    var getTemplate = function (promise) {
        return "<div cg-busy=\"{promise:" + promise + ", message:'', templateUrl:busyModulTemplateURL, minDuration:500}\" > </div>";
    }

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (angular.isDefined(attrs.promise)) {
            var parent = angular.element(document.getElementById('modulSpinner'));

            parent.html(getTemplate(attrs.promise));
            $compile(parent.contents())(scope);
            parent.show();
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: linker
    };
}]);
```

In html i have this:

```
<div class="search-form" ng-controller="autoCompleteController">
    <input type="search" ng-model="searchText" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" placeholder="@Translator.Translate(" SEARCH_OFFER ")" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event);SearchOnEnter($event)" ng-change="search()" ng-enter="Search(searchText)">
    <ul class="suggestions-list" ng-if="isExpanded">
        <li ng-repeat="suggestion in searchItems track by $index" ng-class="{active : selectedIndex === $index}" ng-click="assignValueAndHide($index)">{{suggestion}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="primary-button search-button" ng-click="Search(searchText)"></button>
    <div modul-spinner promise="autoCompletePromise"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have made restrict as 'E" but you are using it as an attribute. Use `<module-spinner></module-spinner>`

Comment: That's right (comment above) and I don't see any element with `modulSpinner` id